# Perl DBD::CSV No such file or directory on Windows

Tags: windows, perl, csv, dbi

I must migrate my perlscripts to a new machine but DBD::CSV would not work as I expect.

I got ActiveState perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread

DBD-CSV is Version 0.41 and everyting I try results in:

```
#################################################################
DBD::CSV::db do failed: 

Execution ERROR: -d D:\TEST/D:\TEST: No such file or directory at D:/Programme/Perl/site/lib/DBI/DBD/SqlEngine.pm line 1503.
 called from D:\TEST\CSVTest.pl at 7.
#################################################################
```

even at the simplest create TestTable

```
#################################################################
use DBI;

$dbh = DBI->connect ("dbi:CSV:");

my $table ="TestTable";

$dbh->do ("CREATE TABLE $table (id INTEGER, name CHAR (64))");
#################################################################
```

Any suggestion?

#### Update

Not the real answer, but too much for an comment the uncommented $DBDIR is the way i had excpeted to work. All the commented versions of $DBDIR I tried, but all created an foo.csv in same directory as the script (C:\Temp). I want to use some other Directory as the Script is located any sugestion?

```
use DBI;
my $DBDIR='C:\Temp\CSV-DB';
# my $DBDIR="C:\\Temp\\CSV-DB";
# my $DBDIR='C:\Temp\CSV-DB\\';
# my $DBDIR='..\CSV-DB';
# my $DBDIR="..\\CSV-DB";
# my $DBDIR='CSV-DB';
# my $DBDIR='\CSV-DB';
# my $DBDIR='\\CSV-DB';
# my $DBDIR='.\CSV-DB';
# my $DBDIR='/CSV-DB';
# my $DBDIR='./CSV-DB';
$dbh = DBI->connect ("dbi:CSV:", undef, undef, {
    f_dir               => [$DBDIR],
    #f_dir_search       => [$DBDIR],
    f_ext      => ".csv/r",
    RaiseError => 1,
    }) or die "Cannot connect: $DBI::errstr";

# Simple statements
$dbh->do ("CREATE TABLE foo (id INTEGER, name CHAR (10))");
##############################################################
```

Comment: add 'or die "Cannot connect: $DBI::errstr"' to get error reporting form your connect() call.

Comment: WTF!! it occures only in Komodo IDE wth debugging. Without debug it seems to work. (the table creation)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on my windows PC.

I found that it occurred when DBI was not the first module to be used.
By putting "use DBI;" as the first module the problem has disappeared.
I haven't tried to determine exactly which module caused the problem. I'm using CGI, Archive::Zip, POSIX, etc..